# Saving .xml on client javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

im looking for a solution to write a file on the clientside that has .xml as file extention.

im using p5.js, so i get the save() function, makes it quite easy for me to save files, but it will add .txt to the file.

Whats the best way to export data in xml on the client?

Thats my code on the client.

```
function exportFixture(){

    let data = [];

    let standartHeader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    let maHeader = '<MA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.malighting.de/grandma2/xml/MA" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.malighting.de/grandma2/xml/MA http://schemas.malighting.de/grandma2/xml/3.3.4/MA.xsd" major_vers="3" minor_vers="3" stream_vers="4">';

    data.push(standartHeader);
    data.push(maHeader);

    save(data, "text.xml");
    // alert("Exported fixture");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `saveStrings(list,filename,[extension])` [method](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveStrings) and rewrite your save call like:

```
saveStrings(data, "text", "xml");
```

Alternatively, you can just rewrite the call to the save method like so:

```
save(data, "text", "xml");
```

Both ways worked for me.

Comment: oh thank you very much!
everywhere i was looking i could not find this way documented...

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my application,I'm using [downloadjs](https://github.com/rndme/download) something like this:

```
download(data, "mydata.xml", "text/plain");
```

and this is a [Demo](http://pagedemos.com/sxks39b72aqb/5) for HTML file